# (Chosen) Combobox Plugin using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, combobox, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

html is below

```
 select(data-placeholder="Choose State", ng-model="districtCourtState")#stateselected                   
    option( ng-repeat='state in StatesofIndia', value= "{{state}}") {{state}}
```

The Above code is part of `ng-controller='inputForm_Controller'` which is included and shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $(".chosen-select").chosen(); 
    $("#stateselected").chosen().change( function() {
       alert($scope.districtCourtState);      
    });
});
```

The above gives the correct Chosen Option Alert, the first time, but from 2nd time onwards for StatesofIndia = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

It consistantly gives selection + 1 as value of `$scope.districtCourtState` ie if "a" is selected `alert` of "b" is given and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs) explains the implementation of jQuery plugin in Angularjs.

Note, using the latest jQuery library: `chosn-select` has to be replaced by `chosen-select` and `liszt: update` is to be replaced by `chosen:updated` when change is triggered.

[This](https://github.com/simpulton/angular-chosen) is the latest github repository. Node the following [unresolved issue](https://github.com/simpulton/angular-chosen/issues/4) though.